# Setting template mode to CP doesn't let me load plugin templates

Tags: plugin-development, templating

Setting template mode to CP with `craft()->templates->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::CP)` only lets me load templates from `app/templates`.

If i load `app/templates/entries/_fields.html` and I use custom fields in the entry, this will attempt to load those edit templates from `plugins/{pluginName}/templates` and I receive an error because the templates could not be found in `app/templates`.

Shouldn't templateMode -> CP behave more like proper CP and not just set a single load path?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you're after 100%, maybe you're looking to call `craft()->templates->setTemplatesPath()` directly and give it your plugin's template path?

Comment: @BradBell I know I can do that, but I can't include a plugin template that includes a CP-template, or a CP-template that includes a plugin-template. Say that I include `app/templates/entries/_fields.html` and the entry has a Neo-matrix, or Supertable or something like that, then I get template errors because the CP-template is trying to include templates that only exists in the respective plugin(s)